# MySQL - using "as" in inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables I am selecting from and two of them have same column named "id". It is `language.id` and `route.id`

If I run this query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM route
 LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
   ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
 LEFT JOIN language
   ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
 WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
```

It runs fine, it cuts `language.id`, which is what I want
However I want to use it as inner select, but when I do this

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM route
     LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
       ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
     LEFT JOIN language
       ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
     WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
   ) T1
```

It ends with `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'`

I have tried renaming it, this query runs fine showing `noneed_id` column as expected

```
 SELECT *, language.id as noneed_id
 FROM route
 LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
   ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
 LEFT JOIN language
   ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
 WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
```

But once again, using it as inner select ends with same error

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT *, language.id as noneed_id
     FROM route
     LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
       ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
     LEFT JOIN language
       ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
     WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
   ) T1
```

I do not understand this behaviour, anyone can point me out?

PS : I know I can do something like this to make it work, but I would like to not name all tables/columns

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT route.*, route_has_languages.*, language.short_name, language.long_name
     FROM route
     LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
       ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
     LEFT JOIN language
       ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
     WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
   ) T1
```

---

If someone wants to try it, you can run this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `short_name` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  `long_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
  `flag` TEXT NULL,
  `language_order` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `short_name_UNIQUE` (`short_name` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `long_name_UNIQUE` (`long_name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `length` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `estimated_time` INT NOT NULL,
  `accessibility` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `version` INT NOT NULL,
  `north_east_point_lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `north_east_point_lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `south_west_point_lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `south_west_point_lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `available` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `store_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(63) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route_has_languages` (
  `route_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `languages_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `voice` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
  `info_at_poi` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`route_id`, `languages_id`),
  INDEX `fk_route_has_languages_languages1_idx` (`languages_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_route_has_languages_route1_idx` (`route_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_route_has_languages_route1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`route_id`)
    REFERENCES `audioguide`.`route` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_route_has_languages_languages1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`languages_id`)
    REFERENCES `audioguide`.`language` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Did you try inner query like this `SELECT language.id as noneed_id, *  FROM route`. Just exchanged `*` and `language.id as noneed_id`

Comment: Where is language.id coming from ?

Comment: @MRSrinivas - You cant do this, it ends with "You have an error in your SQL syntax" and even MySQL workbench shows it as error even before executing it.

Comment: Dont you think this is wrong  SELECT *, language.id as noneed_id
     FROM route ?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion - I do not understand question, it is column id coming from table language... similar as route.id is column id from table route.

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion - No, it is not wrong, as I said in topic, it runs fine when not in inner select.

Comment: **[Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)** - Although aimed at SQL Server the principals apply to all DBMS. In short, don't use `SELECT *`, there is no good reason other than laziness to not type out the column list and only return the columns you need. Even if your query works because there are no duplicate column names, someone might add a column at some point, so even though nothing in your query has changed, it will start throwing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use `*` in both `SELECT` statements, you will have this error.

Renaming it like: `, language.id as noneed_id` will only **add** a column, but it will not remove the `id` column(s).

A solution can be to rename the fields in the database. For example, `route.id` to `route_id` etc.

Comment: What is the reason you are reluctant to explicitly type all the fields in the query? Maybe if we know the reason for this, we can help to find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

**Lets check the Problem-**

Your first query-

```
SELECT *
 FROM route
 LEFT JOIN route_has_languages
   ON route.id = route_has_languages.route_id
 LEFT JOIN language
   ON language.id = route_has_languages.languages_id
 WHERE route_has_languages.languages_id = 1
```

Here mysql will follow fields order as per table order means first table all fields then 2nd table all fields and so on as per below-

In your second table you are using sub-query means mysql will treat same and povide results as per below-

```
id (first table), col12,col13,col14..., id(2nd table),col22,col23,col24..., other tables columns.....
```

means your results are -

```
id,col11,col12,col13,...,id,col21,col22,col23,....
```

Now your outer query will fetch results from here and will get id column 2 times and will throw error.

**Solution**

Either you have to mention all columns in sub-query and need to keep different alias for common fields or need to change column name in one table.

Comment: Ok, the real question is, when I run the subquery, it does not return multiple columns with same ID, the id column is only one there. Why it is not propagated to the outer select as it is?

Comment: route and language both tables have id field means sub-query will return id 2 times here mysql manage columns in same order as in tables in join but in outer query now there are 2 columns physically with same name due to which mysql is throwing errors as select statement can't have 2 columns with same name.